# MySQL update one table from another joined many-to-many

Tags: mysql, join, update

I have two tables, `events` and `plays` joined many-to-many by a third table `plays_in_events`.

Where the events.Name field is blank, I want to set it equal to the name of the play that was performed in that linked event.

I have tried

```
UPDATE `events` 
  INNER JOIN `events` ON (`plays_in_events`.`EventID` = `events`.`EventID`)
  INNER JOIN `plays` ON (`plays_in_events`.`PlayID` = `plays`.`PlayID`)
  SET events.Name = plays.Play
WHERE 
  events.Name IS NULL and plays_in_events.PlayID = 1
```

but get a syntax error

```
SQL Error: Not unique table/alias: 'events'
```

(I'm trying to limit any damage from accidental multiple updates by only testing it in the first instance for PlayID = 1, but have hundreds of records to update, so I don't want to do it manually).

There is only one table `events` in the database.

What's going wrong here please? I can't see it, unfortunately.

LATER

Maybe I've got the JOIN wrong altogether.

This SELECT query works to join the two main tables, and was produced by a visual query editor:

```
SELECT 
  `events`.`EventID`, `events`.`Name`, `plays`.`Play`, `plays`.`PlayID`
FROM
  `plays_in_events`
  INNER JOIN `events` ON (`plays_in_events`.`EventID` = `events`.`EventID`)
  INNER JOIN `plays` ON (`plays_in_events`.`PlayID` = `plays`.`PlayID`)
WHERE
  `events`.`Name` IS NULL AND 
  `plays`.`PlayID` < 10
```

How could I make the JOINS in the UPDATE based on this working?

Comment: What is `plays_in_events`? It is nowhere to be seen in your query but in the last line

Comment: I thought it was a alias issue, but yeah I think it's typo. You have events table twice; one should be plays_in_events :P

Comment: The tables are joined events <--plays_in_events-->plays. The plays in events table has link fields EventID and PlayID.

Comment: @cha asked "What is `plays_in_events`" -- it's the table making the many-to-many relationship between `events` and `plays`and appears twice in the INNER JOINS as well as in the last line.

Comment: @cha and I'm saying you have typographical error in query statement. You don't have `plays_in_events` table in your joins. Instead, you wrote `events` table twice.

Comment: @MannyCalavera: I am not the OP

Comment: Maybe I've got the JOIN wrong - this SELECT query works to join the tables, and I tried to copy it to the UPDATE query.    SELECT 
  `events`.`EventID`,
  `events`.`Name`,
  `plays`.`Play`,
  `plays`.`PlayID`
FROM
  `plays_in_events`
  INNER JOIN `events` ON (`plays_in_events`.`EventID` = `events`.`EventID`)
  INNER JOIN `plays` ON (`plays_in_events`.`PlayID` = `plays`.`PlayID`)
WHERE
  `events`.`Name` IS NULL AND 
  `plays`.`PlayID` < 10

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how to format the query as code in a Comment. Maybe I should edit the original question?

Answer (score 2):

This works - I had the JOIN wrong

```
UPDATE `events` 
  INNER JOIN `plays_in_events` ON (`plays_in_events`.`EventID` = `events`.`EventID`)
  INNER JOIN `plays` ON (`plays_in_events`.`PlayID` = `plays`.`PlayID`)
  SET events.Name = plays.Play
WHERE 
  events.Name IS NULL and plays_in_events.PlayID = 1
```

and the earlier comments were quite right, but it took me a while to 'get it' - thanks for your help. I had just copied the JOIN lines from the working SELECT query, but when I looked again, I could finally see what the commentators meant about `events` appearing twice, and `plays_in_events` not appearing properly in the JOINs.